# Net::SMTPUnknownError (could not get 3xx (550)) when sending email from Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, google-apps, spf

I read many answers how should I set SPF record, spf documentation, but I'm still getting this error and I have no idea why.

I've got 2 servers, on the first one I've got example.com and on the second I'm running rails app under account.example.com.

I setup spf record: `"v=spf1 a mx ip4:ip-of-second-server include:_spf.google.com -all"`

My smtp settings:

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  :address => 'smtp.gmail.com',
  :port => 587,
  :domain => 'example.com',
  :authentication => 'plain',
  :user_name => ENV['GMAIL_USERNAME'],
  :password => ENV['GMAIL_PASSWORD']
}
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

We had a similar issue on our Heroku App using a gmail account to send us notifications. Not sure if you situation is exactly the same but this is how we recovered.

When a huge spike in mails occurred, Google marked the alias as 'exceeding sending limit' ( see http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=166852) , and we began to see the 3xx 550 errors in our Heroku logs.

1. we reenabled the account via Gmail ( see http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1071520)
2. we added SPF record for our domain ( see http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=178723)

this resolved our 3xx 550 errors.

Comment: keep in mind "The restriction on sending new mail typically lasts for one hour, but can last as long as 24 hours"; so you may want to try a new email alias for a quicker resolution